# Mule Application is not sending response

Tags: rest, mule, esb

My first Application is calling an other application but am not getting any response if i call the second application directly from SoapUI am getting response please help

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <flow name="stackFlow1" doc:name="stackFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="example.com/main" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" method="POST" doc:name="seconapp.co.io/flow"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The Second application xml is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">
    <flow name="secondflowFlow1" doc:name="secondflowFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="seconapp.co.io/flow" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="CXF"/>
        <logger message="hello" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure the second app's endpoint is listeing on localhost, actually given that you use a hostname it is not:

```
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="seconapp.co.io/flow" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

You should try to change your first app outbound endpoint to:

```
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="seconapp.co.io" path="flow" port="8081" method="POST" doc:name="seconapp.co.io/flow"/>
```